# Unordered list falls appart html

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've been struggling over 2 hours over this and i dont know the solution...

I'm trying to create a nested list, with every row containing the following items:

picture of a fruit | a bar chart | some values

picture of a fruit | a bar chart | some values

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rq5AJ/

and this is the result im getting:

picture of a fruit | a bar chart | some values

```
                            picture of a fruit
```

| a bar chart | some values

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

removing the font seems to help, any idea why?

```
.mgValue{
    text-align:center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-size:18px;
    color:#7D7D60;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family:'GOTHICB';
}

.gValue{
    color:#A09F8E;
    font-size:14px;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'GOTHICB';
    src:url(../Fonts/GOTHICB.TTF);
}
```

Comment: a) it doesn't make much sense to use an html list for a set of completely different types of objects.  b) if you drop your code into JsFiddle.net or Codepen.io you can replicate the problem, then provide it to us so we can more easily tinker with your code.

Comment: Seems like a table better fits your data instead of nested lists

Comment: so I added the jsfiddle link, and there when I dragged the result to be large enough it was working as it should... tho in my browser it is still falling appart...

Comment: I changed the list to a table as @StephenThomas suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting this improperly. Each of your ul elements should be an li element. You can then proceed to format the data inside of each li element with CSS. But, as your li elements are not similar items, but rather different types of data, it would make more sense to format this way.

Alternatively, just wrap each group of items in a div with a class of "fruit(or whatever)" and then style the elements inside of the div.